# Paste two vectors at only specified positions

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

```
vec1 <- c("222", "AA-AA", "GGH-GGH", "GGGD")
vec2 <- c("222", "AA-AA", "GGG-GGH", "GGGD")
```

I would like to paste them at defined positions only

```
postions <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

The result I want is

```
222-222, AA-AA, GGH-GGH, GGGD-GGGD)
```

How do I get this in R?

I tried `paste(vec1[positions], vec2[positions], sep = "-")` but did not get as expected.

### UPDATE:

This is the actual data:

```
vec1 <- c("226883824", "226883824", "226883824", "232844096", "232844096", 
"232844096", "232844096", "232847517-232847519", "232847517-232847519", 
"232847517-232847519", "232847517-232847519", "232847538", "232847538", 
"232847538", "232847538")

vec2 <- c("226883824", "226883824", "226883824", "232844096", "232844096", 
"232844096", "232844096", "232847517-232847519", "232847517-232847519", 
"232847517-232847519", "232847517-232847519", "232847538", "232847538", 
"232847538", "232847538")

positions <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
```

So, in my solution, I do not want anything appended to `"232847517-232847519",  "232847517-232847519", "232847517-232847519"` as they already have what I intend to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, we can use indexing on the logical vector to subset both the `vector`s, `paste` and assign the output back to one of the vector

```
vec1[postions] <- paste(vec1[postions], vec2[postions], sep="-")
vec1
#[1] "222-222"   "AA-AA"     "GGH-GGH"   "GGGD-GGGD"
```

With OP's new data

```
vec1[positions] <- paste(vec1[positions], vec2[positions], sep="-")
vec1
#[1] "226883824-226883824" "226883824-226883824" "226883824-226883824" "232844096-232844096" "232844096-232844096" "232844096-232844096"
#[7] "232844096-232844096" "232847517-232847519" "232847517-232847519" "232847517-232847519" "232847517-232847519" "232847538-232847538"
#[13] "232847538-232847538" "232847538-232847538" "232847538-232847538"
```

---

Or with `ifelse/strrep` (using the OP's updated dataset)

```
trimws(ifelse(grepl("-", vec1), vec1,
       strrep(paste0(vec1, "-"), 2)), whitespace = "-")
#[1] "226883824-226883824" "226883824-226883824" "226883824-226883824" "232844096-232844096" "232844096-232844096" "232844096-232844096"
#[7] "232844096-232844096" "232847517-232847519" "232847517-232847519" "232847517-232847519" "232847517-232847519" "232847538-232847538"
#[13] "232847538-232847538" "232847538-232847538" "232847538-232847538"
```

Comment: It doesn't put delimiter.

Comment: @New_to_R i updated it.  Initially, I was confused because of the single object

Comment: I am getting incorrect result with actual data. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @New_to_R is it because the `positions` vector have some incorrect TRUE values?

Comment: No. Those are booleans only

Comment: @New_to_R can you please try on a fresh vec1, vec2 assignment because I am guessing that you are applying  the assignment on the already modified vec1

Comment: @New_to_R Can you test it as I couldn't reproduce the issue